# Click for button access parent object?

Tags: jquery

trying to get object within click event. What am I doing wrong here?
this.section is index for each button.

```
  this.ebutton        = jQuery('.episode_button');
  this.button         = this.ebutton.eq(this.section);
  this.listtext       = 'testbutton';

  this.button.parobj  = this;
  this.button.bind('click', function() {

    alert(this.parobj.listtext());

   });
```

How can I get the property listtext within the button event?

Comment: Ok fixed it. Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

tried

```
$("#"+this.id).parent()
```

or

```
$(<selector>).parent()
```

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Well, i'm not interested in getting the parent element, but the object in the code, which holds the button. So I can reference each object within the function that triggers after the push of button.

Comment: i need a bit better description to what you are attempting to achieve?

You can 

'click', function(event) {event.preventDefault();
});

Comment: this still didn't help. **what are you attempting to do?** If you want to get the object which you clicked you should be using this inside the function (){ this} 
Bear in mind if you have this you can trace back the button object as you can get the ID and then put that into jquery to get the object

Comment: Got it working with **[.data()](http://example.com)**

`this.button.data("obj", this);
        this.button.bind('click', function() {jQuery(this).data("obj").episodelistshow();});`

Answer (score 0):

```
     var epi = {};

     /*Startpage*/
     epi.start = {
         epilist:            [],

         init: function () {
             this.ebutton                = jQuery('.episode_button');
             this.episodelist.prototype  = this;

             this.epilist.push(new this.episodelist(0));
         },


         episodelist: function (index) {
             this.name           = 'test'
             this.button         = this.ebutton.eq(index);
             this.button.parobj  = this;
             this.button.bind('click', function() {this.parobj.episodelistshow();});
         },

         episodelistshow: function () {

             // This will not alert correctly!
             // Should alert test
              alert(this.name);            

         }
     }​
```